# How to resolve npm issue

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install npm version 6.9.0 using command `npm install --global npm@6.9.0`

And I'm getting following error

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/.staging/npm-0fd8a334/node_modules/yargs
npm ERR! dest /root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/.staging/yargs-71bc3a6a
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 0:0 "/root/.npm"
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-12-01T10_31_32_191Z-debug.log
```

I've tried `sudo chown -R 0:0 "/root/.npm"` cleaning npm cache but nothing works.
I'm using ubuntu 20.04 (WSL) How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do `sudo npm install --global npm@6.9.0`